# The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request

Tags: php, mysql, apache

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, nkutty@bics.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.2.0 (Fedora) Server at bbt.com Port 80
```

This works fine in my local system but it is not working in the server.

Comment: please look at the server logs.

Comment: `More information about this error may be available in the server error log.` Is there any more information in the server log? This is a generic Apache error meaning "some other component encountered an error"; typically, it might be an error in your PHP script (different directory paths on devel and live? Access permissions in filesystem? Access error in database?)

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log

Answer (score 52):

Check your servers error log, typically `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Answer (score 32):

You should look for the error in the file error_log in the log directory. Maybe there are differences between your local and server configuration (db user/password etc.etc.)

usually the log file is in

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

or

```
/var/log/httpd/error.log
```

Comment: How can I check them on the server?

Comment: On Server : 
Through Putty :
tail - f /var/log/apache2/error.log

if using core ftp or filezilla or winscp, than just go folder to folder.

Comment: I am using filezilla, unable to find such file / folder on server.